# Using CPU counters versus gettimeofday?

Tags: c, linux, profiling

I'd like to profile some code in C using Linux. I usually just do the usual `gettimeofday()` functions, they're easy to put in, understandable, and portable. I've had someone ask me why not using CPU counters or RDTSC for profiling the code, but although I understand that RDTSC may be more precise, I cannot argue in favor or against one or the other. So, my question is: all else being equal, would people profile code with the usual time functions or the RDTSC?

Comment: Any reason to not to just use a profiler tool like `gprof`?

Comment: "POSIX.1-2008 marks `gettimeofday()` as obsolete, recommending the use of `clock_gettime(2)` instead."

Comment: only profiling short portions of parallel code... you have to patch gprof for profiling threads. perf would be better, but you cannot time individual portions of code.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Obsolete meaning it doesn't work? What does "obsolete" mean?

Comment: RDTSC is slightly harder to use because it's not standard and you need to figure out how many "ticks" there are per unit of time.

Comment: `clock_t clock(void)` is not precise enough ? The problème with RDTSC is that it will count context switches as part as the running time of your process -- or the function has to be short enough to fit between context switches..

Comment: @DervinThunk Obsolete means out-of-date, going to be forgotten/abolished. It will still work for a while, but support for it won't hang around forever, probably.

Comment: @Mysticial: unless you have Invariant TSC available (`CPUID.80000007H:EDX[8]`), then the tick is constant. @OP: Chapter 30.11 of Intel's Architecture manula (Vol. 3A & 3B) goes in-depth into the inner workings of profiling/clock-counting with the TSC if you really can't use an off the shelf profiler.

Comment: @Necrolis: I just want to see the running time of a portion of my parallel code, in the simplest possible way, that's all.

Comment: @DervinThunk If you just want the running time, then just a real time function. Don't mess with RDTSC unless you need to.

Comment: @Mysticial: Exactly what I thought, I just can't argue back why... :(

Comment: @DervinThunk You're basically asking for a time function. Then you might as use an out-of-the-box time function such as `gettimeofday()` and family. RDTSC is very low level. If you want you use that instead to get time, you'll probably be reimplementing most of what the existing time functions already do.

Comment: @DervinThunk: you might find this a good summary of API vs low-level timing then: http://aufather.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/high-performance-time-measuremen-in-linux/

Comment: Can people write down answers, so I can give proper credit in the form of upvotes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPU counters and wall clocks are different tools for different purposes.

**When to use a wall clock:**

When you want to measure time in a standard time unit (such as seconds). If you want to measure how long X task takes, use a wall clock.

Examples:

- `clock()`
- `gettimeofday()`
- `clock_gettime(2)`
- etc...

**When to use RDTSC:**

If you're looking to measure the *relative* times of two different tasks to as high precision as possible, then RDTSC may be suitable.

RDTSC measures the number of pseudo-cycles that have elapsed since the CPU has started up. Often (but not always), this is equal to the CPU clock speed of your processor. But there's no easy to determine the exact number of "ticks per second" without actually measuring it against a wall clock.

However, RDTSC is about as low overhead as it can get for a time function. So it is well suited for micro-optimizations when you're comparing one implementation against another to determine which is *faster*. (as opposed to how much absolute time it takes)

---

Other things to note:

- In most cases, most benchmarking purposes can be done sufficiently well with wall clocks. So the use of RDTSC is pretty limited. Stick with standardized functions when possible.
- High precision wall clocks are typically implemented on top of RDTSC. So if you're trying to use RDTSC to get a high-precision measurement of wall time, you'll just be reinventing the wheel.

<sub>As a side note, I use RDTSC both for seeing RNGs and as an anti-cheating measure for my overclocker benchmarks.</sub>

Comment: A minor note: clock_gettime() supports different clocks to adapt to both use cases (see eg CLOCK_MONOTONIC)

Answer (score 3):

For most purposes, I would use `clock_gettime`. As others have said, `gettimeofday` is obsolescent and its resolution is too low for measuring times in the sub-10000-cycle range. Note that `clock_gettime` *may* have syscall overhead (kernel entry/exit cost) reflected in the differences you take, but on modern x86_64 Linux systems, `clock_gettime` actually runs fully in userspace and uses `rdtsc` under the hood, so it ends up just being a much more portable, cleanly abstracted version of `rdtsc`.

Comment: yes.  RDTSC is just another form of "all the world's a VAX" style programming, just of the Intel flavor.  Stick with the portable interfaces wherever possible.

Comment: so, just to make sure, `gettimeofday()` is functionally equivalent to `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`?

Comment: No, `gettimeofday` corresponds to `CLOCK_REALTIME`. That's another reason to avoid `gettimeofday`; it's subject to be wrong for measuring intervals if the clock is reset. `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` works reliably even if the clock is reset. You can also opt for `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_CLOCKID` if you want to just measure the cpu time spent by your process, not including other processes that might preempt it.